# How to fix Prisma Error: Error opening a TLS connection: error:24067044:random number generator

Tags: javascript, node.js, prisma

Error:

[image]

Getting this error, using a Node js, prisma version 4.8.1.
The server is deployed in a Docker container based on FROM node:14-slim to Elastic beanstalk.

Reproducing the issue is very tricky as it only happens rarely, only on ARM instances.

I don't know how to fix it.